# How to plot an alternative to PCA of a categorical variable based on categorical/discrete factors with R?

Tags: r, graph, categorical-data

I would like to create a plot in R out of this dataset:

```
     rep trt tme  loc SP
1    1   D   I    A   sp1
2    1   G   I    A   sp2
3    1   T   I    A   sp3
4    1   D   II   A   sp2
5    1   F   II   A   sp1
6    1   T   II   A   sp1
7    1   D   III  A   sp1
8    1   G   III  A   sp1
9    1   T   III  A   sp4
10   1   D   IV   A   sp1
11   1   G   IV   A   sp2
12   1   T   IV   A   sp2
13   1   D   I    B   sp2
14   1   G   I    B   sp2
15   1   T   I    B   sp1
16   1   D   II   B   sp1
17   1   G   II   B   sp3
18   1   T   II   B   sp4
19   1   D   III  B   sp4
20   1   G   III  B   sp4
21   1   T   III  B   sp4
22   1   D   IV   B   sp2
23   1   G   IV   B   sp2
24   1   T   IV   B   sp2
25   1   D   I    C   sp2
26   1   G   I    C   sp2
27   1   T   I    C   sp1
28   1   D   II   C   sp1
29   1   G   II   C   sp1
30   1   T   II   C   sp1
31   1   D   III  C   sp1
32   1   G   III  C   sp4
33   1   T   III  C   sp4
34   1   D   IV   C   sp4
35   1   G   IV   C   sp2
36   1   T   IV   C   sp5
37   2   D   I    A   sp5
38   2   G   I    A   sp1
...
1350 30  T   IV   C   sp8
```

Three categorical factors (`trt, tme, loc`) and one categorical variable (`SP`) with 30 replicates (`rep`).

I am not an expert in the matter and I am not used to work with this type of data. The kind of graph that I want to obtain is this: [image: PCA]

I hope that you can help me and that this question is not repeated.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Since PCA works only with numeric variables, that is not going to work for you. Some kind of correspondence analysis might make sense but you should probably be asking on Cross Validated for statistical advice.

Comment: Agree that PCA is for numeric data.  If you have some domain knowledge that tme=I is closer to tme=II than it is to tme=III, for example, then you could start to convert that to a numeric variable.  But you'd still need to balance the relative importance of differences in tme vs differences in loc - if you could do all that you could work out pairwise distances (between rows) and then `cdmscale` would do something similar to PCA, starting from that distance matrix.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your advice.